# Possible to import and apply multiple animations for one pre-rigged model?

Tags: modeling, animation

I’m working with imported pre-rigged models and pre-made animation files from a couple video games. Since the models are already rigged and the animations are already made, is it possible to import and combine multiple animations/actions for one model to make a longer sequence instead of having them all be separate blender files and separate animations? Thanks!

Comment: There is the [Pose Library](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/animation/armatures/posing/editing/pose_library.html) that seems to hold entire sequences. It may do what you want. Exploring that is on my to-do list...

Comment: The short answer is yes. But what are you going to do with them? Are you trying so combine them into long storytelling animation, or you want to edit them and add more?

Comment: This is what NLA editor is there for.